# Is it possible to stream the Audio Channel through multiple devices

Tags: android, iphone, audio, audio-streaming

So here we are,

3 college students. My parents live at my place ;) and i have two friends that are often here to hang out. We like movies ... a looot .

The problem is, often, we cannot enjoy the full sound experience. 
Reasons ? It's too loud :(
My parents get easily annoyed and i have a little brother who goes early to bed. No movies after 22:00 :(

So we tried to squeeze our little brains :)
**Our solution :**
**Stream the audio channel of my PC to our devices**
Each of us has a Smartphone. We thought, that everyone of us can somehow get the stream
We call it a **Silent Movie Party :)**

How can we do this ? Is there software available ? Or can we program it somehow ?
I am a CS undergrad, but i think i could handle that with the right instructions.

**Justice League : We need your help !**

Comment: You'll never get it adequately in sync to your liking.  Just get a wireless headphone transmitter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. (If you really want it :)

You need for web-service (local/global) and some software to translate audio stream to target devices. There a lot of exists solution (http://www.wowza.com/), but you could try to create your own. I don't know how it work in Android, but for iOS Apple provides for this aims - [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).